# Touchpad cursor keeps moving in the same direction for a second after I stop

Tags: windows, windows-10

It's like the touchpad is sensing the width of my fingertip and something thinks the cursor should reach the end of the detected-surface of my fingertip before it should stop, even after I've stopped moving my finger. This isn't a normal experience with laptops. How can I go about making the cursor, like other laptops, stop when I stop my finger? To be clear, the cursor stops when I take my finger off the touchpad, but it keeps going for a second when I stop my finger and my finger is still touching the touchpad, again, like it's trying to reach the end of the detected-surface of my fingertip before it stops.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using?
With Windows 10 you can usually adjust the touch pad within the settings
The control panel provides a good amount of extra setting adjustments also.

But Possibly could be you need to fix the sensitivity or check if it
has a delayed effect setting possibly?

I'm not able to paste pictures yet, But they provided 
a redirection link. 
[Settings > Devices > Touchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWTJA.png)

I believe even these mouse settings would have an impact on your cursor
[Control Panel Mouse Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSwX5.png)

Comment: Nevermind about the OS, sorry I just noticed the tags.

Comment: None of those setting appear like they would solve the problem.

Comment: Try running the Hardware and Devices Troubleshooter to diagnose the issue. This tool will also help in resolving the problem it detects on the system. Follow these steps to perform the suggestion:

    Click on Start.
    Type Troubleshooting then press Enter.
    On the left panel, click on View all.
    Choose Hardware and Devices and allow the troubleshooter to run.


Also see if all your drives for HID in Device manager are up to date.
 - right click start menu
 - Device manager
 - and try to manually update all your drivers that way.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**
within the SYNAPTIC TOUCHPAD SETTINGS **disable momentum.**

**Detail:**
I was able to fix this problem on my windows 10 msi laptop.
On my laptop the cursor/mouse would continue moving across the screen when i lifted my finger if my movement was faster it would move further, and would stop if I kept my finger on the touch pad, it is only when lifting the finger during a fast movement. Hence the term Momentum.
Not sure how it got like this for me, maybe I was playing with the settings previously.
I do not think the make/model matters as this looks to be a common setting within:
SYNAPTICS TOUCHPAD SETTINGS

**Follow this:**
open windows settings
navigate to touchpad settings
select additional settings
a standard windows window will pop up and will provide 6-7+ tabs at the top.
one of those tabs will be Device Settings, select it.
Device or Synaptics.... will be present on Port PS/2 maybe (not that this really matters)
under the white device panel there is a settings button, select it.
SYNAPTIC SETTINGS will pop open

within the SYNAPTIC TOUCHPAD SETTINGS window, select Pointing, then Momentum.
**disable momentum.**

Done